# Closing amqp.Channel when consumer is failed is not responding

Tags: go, amqp

I use https://github.com/NeowayLabs/wabbit/
When amqp.Channel is closing after wrong try channel.Consume, we have a not listened chan and function is not responding.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/NeowayLabs/wabbit"
    "github.com/NeowayLabs/wabbit/amqptest"
    "github.com/NeowayLabs/wabbit/amqptest/server"
)

func someFunc(amqpURL string) error {
    conn, err := amqptest.Dial(amqpURL)
    defer conn.Close()

    channel, err := conn.Channel()
    defer channel.Close()

    consumer, err := channel.Consume(
        "queue",
        "consumer",
        wabbit.Option{},
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err  // err = "Unknown queue 'queue'", but we never response it
    }

    fmt.Println(<-consumer)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    amqpURL := "127.0.0.1:32773"
    fakeServer := server.NewServer(amqpURL)
    err := fakeServer.Start()
    defer fakeServer.Stop()

    err = someFunc(amqpURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Happy end")
}
```

someFunc never responding with error, but I want to handle consumer errors.

Answer (score 0):

`someFunc` never responds with an error because it gets hung up in the `defer` code.

When `someFunc` gets to the `return err` line, then it tries to run the `defer` statements that you set up in the beginning of the function. The first one that it tries is `defer channel.Close()`.

The problem seems to be with this block in the wabbit library: https://github.com/NeowayLabs/wabbit/blob/d8bc549279ecd80204a8a83a868a14fdd81d1a1b/amqptest/server/channel.go#L315-L317

I think, although I am not sure, that writing to the `consumer.done` channel is a blocking operation because the channel is not buffered and does not have a receiver. See this: https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations for more information.

I commented that block of code out when running this locally and found that the rest of the code ran as you expected that it would, finally resulting in a `panic: Unknown queue 'queue'`